# Correct way of merging scRNAseq datasets of healthy and tumor cell?

Tags: python, scrnaseq

While merging datasets from similar biological conditions, but different experimental conditions is a well-studied topic, and there are many batch correction techniques available. What I want to understand is the right way to merge scRNA seq counts data of healthy and tumor cells.

Does individually log-normalising the counts, followed by a simple concatenation of the objects works, or there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that you've tagged this as python, but unfortunately I'm most familiar with doing single cell analysis using R. Perhaps there's a python way to do something similar.

Seurat has recently included a workflow for reciprocal PCA integration, which the authors claim should work well when the combined datasets are more different than usual:

> RPCA-based integration runs significantly faster, and also represents a more conservative approach where cells in different biological states are less likely to ‘align’ after integration. We therefore, recommend RPCA during integrative analysis where:
>
> - A substantial fraction of cells in one dataset have no matching type in the other
> - Datasets originate from the same platform (i.e. multiple lanes of 10x genomics)
> - There are a large number of datasets or cells to integrate (see INSERT LINK for more tips on integrating large datasets)

A tutorial workflow can be found here:

https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/integration_rpca.html

Comment: Indeed, I am a python user, but this is already helpful. Thanks :)